# display navigation items based on isAdmin value node.js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a node.js and express app, in my user model there is a boolean field isAdmin. what i want to do is to hide certain elements in navigation based on whether the logged in user is an admin or not. I have written two helpers auth.js checks if a user is logged in or not, following is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    ensureAuthenticated: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Not Authorized');
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

the other helper is adminCheck.js which checks if the user is an admin or not:

```
module.exports = {
    adminUser: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.user.isAdmin) {
            return next();
        }
        req.flash('error_msg', 'You have tried to access a restricted space. As a result you have been logged out!');
        res.redirect('/logout');
    }
}
```

for my admin related routes i am using these helpers successfully like so:

```
// admin index route 
router.get('/', [ensureAuthenticated, adminUser], (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin/index');
});
```

But the problem is my html, in the navigation i can hide certain elements based on whether the user is logged in or not:

```
   {{#if user}}
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <ul class="list-inline sm-pull-none sm-text-center text-right text-white mb-sm-20 mt-10">
                        <li class="m-0 pl-10">
                            <a href="/logout" class="text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-o mr-5 text-white"></i> logout</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="m-0 pl-10">
                            <a href="/admin" class="text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-o mr-5 text-white"></i> Admin</a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
                {{else}}
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <ul class="list-inline sm-pull-none sm-text-center text-right text-white mb-sm-20 mt-10">
                        <li class="m-0 pl-10">
                            <a href="/login" class="text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-o mr-5 text-white"></i> Login /</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="m-0 pl-0 pr-10">
                            <a href="/register" class="text-white">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit mr-5 text-white"></i>Register</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {{/if}}
```

as you can see in the above html, there is a link to admin, I want to hide that based on the logged in user, how can i do that? what would be custom helper code to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK...so i simply needed to change my statement to

```
{{#if user.isAdmin}}
```